# I have a lot of plastic anchor bolts in the sheetrock walls. What is the best way to patch them?

Tags: patching-drywall

I am moving & after taking down many pictures, mirrors, etc., I have many plastic anchors left in the sheetrock.  What is the best way to patch them?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the design of them, if they're the type that can be removed ( pulled straight out with needle nose pliers) I would yank them then patch them.

If they are the type that don't want to come out easily, sometimes you can take a small ball peen hammer ( using the rounded end )and lightly tap them below surface level... This way, patching can be accomplished.

And finally, if you can't do anything with them  ( in rare cases ) you can drill them out gently, then of course patch.

Answer (score 1):

Vinyl spackle would be my choice. It's easy to work with and dries fast. It doesn't need a second coat like joint compound does.